# How to add integration between TWA and FCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'm struggling with notifications pushes for TWA app. I cannot find any information how to add push notifications (like firebase cloud messages).

If I get it right first step is to get device token to register user phone in the firebase google cloud messages service. I don't understand how to join my web app and native code to get device token. My possible options are:

1. Inject device token into TWA by cookies
2. Inject device token into TWA by adding query param to start url
3. Use web pushes as more native solution for TWA

Answer (score 1):

The easiest/recommended way to get Firebase Cloud Messaging is using Web push. Here's the [Firebase Cloud Messaging Web (JavaScript) documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

Comment: Even for TWA should one go for "Web Push"? Or should we try Android (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)?